# CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT WHEN (condition) DB2

Tags: triggers, insert, db2, after-effects

```
CREATE TRIGGER hundert        
AFTER INSERT ON Leistung  
FOR EACH ROW MODE       DB2SQL  
WHEN(SELECT modulNR, SUM(Prozentanteil) AS summe    
FROM       Leistung     
GROUP BY modulNr    
HAVING SUM(prozentanteil) > 100) 
BEGIN     ATOMIC 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23506'  
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = ('The Sum is       bigger then 100');
END
```

How to create a WHEN statement if i wanna say it has to exam all "prozentanteil" if the sum is bigger then 100?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the syntax diagram for the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement in the manual, you'll see that the `WHEN` clause needs a search condition that returns a boolean value. A subselect by itself cannot return a boolean value. You probably meant to use the `EXISTS` predicate there:

```
...
WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ...)
...
```